# Copy Method Body To Property

Tags: c#, refactoring, roslyn

I am trying to create a new property that has the same body as a method.

Here is my code so far:

```
private async Task<Solution> ConvertMethodToProperty(Document document, MethodDeclarationSyntax methodNode, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    AccessorListSyntax accesors = SyntaxFactory.AccessorList(new SyntaxList<AccessorDeclarationSyntax>
    {
        SyntaxFactory.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration, methodNode.Body)
    });
    PropertyDeclarationSyntax newp = SyntaxFactory.PropertyDeclaration(new SyntaxList<AttributeListSyntax>(), methodNode.Modifiers, methodNode.ReturnType, methodNode.ExplicitInterfaceSpecifier, methodNode.Identifier, accesors);
    SyntaxNode root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    document = document.WithSyntaxRoot(root.ReplaceNode(methodNode, newp));
    return document.Project.Solution;
    }
}
```

However when I run this on my test project I see this:

[image]

Even though the methodNode.Body from the code is populated with the method body I want:

[image]

What am I doing wrong when I create my AccessorListSyntax? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your use of the collection initialiser on the `SyntaxList` is not valid. As that will implicitly call the `Add` method on your SyntaxList but the add doesn't modify the underlying collection it just returns a new SyntaxList. Try instantiating and manually adding afterwards like this.

```
var accessorList = new SyntaxList<AccessorDeclarationSyntax>();
accessorList = accessorList.Add(SyntaxFactory.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration, methodNode.Body));
```

I fell into the same trap when I started playing around with Roslyn, just have to remember the immutability thing.

Comment: Yes, this is a common problem with immutable collections like `SyntaxList`.  You need to observe the result of the .Add() call.

Comment: Or, better yet, just call `SyntaxFactory.SingletonList(...)`